# memcmp - is there a faster way to bitwise compare two buffers

Tags: c++, performance, memory, comparison

I want to most quickly & efficiently find out if two memory buffers - holding arbitrarily defined values - are identical in a bitwise comparision.

I'm not interested in anything but the Boolean "is identical" and I want the method to return as quickly as possible, i.e. at first difference found.

What is the best way to achieve this?
I'm currenlty first comparing the overall size - which I know - and use 
`memcmp` if they are of same size

```
memcmp( buf1_ptr, buf2_ptr, sizeof(buf1) )
```

Is this the most efficient I can do? Should I split the comparison into junks of a for-loop?

Comment: How large are the buffers? Unless they are extremely large, and you can perhaps get some benefit from multiple threads, I doubt you will do better than `memcmp`.

Comment: @BoBTFish : If the buffer is that large, then the limiting factor is probably going to bandwidth between the CPU and the RAM - and I would expect a single core could probably saturate that.

Comment: @MartinBonner That is beyond what I am willing to speculate on given the minimal information presented. I did say *perhaps*.

Comment: Maybe you can try some greedy methods for your specific case. For example if buffers are differences in most cases. You can compare some random bytes, like monte Carlo method methods. If these bytes are the same, use memcpy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, `memcmp` will have been written in assembler by experts.  It is very, very, unlikely you can do any better than them at the general purpose problem it solves.

*If* you can promise that the pointers will always be (eg) aligned on a 16 byte boundary, and that the length will always be a multiple of 16 bytes, you might be able to do a little better by using some vectorized solution like SSE.  (memcmp wil probably end up using SSE too under those circumstances, but it will have to do some tests first to make sure - and you can save the cost of those tests).

Otherwise - just use memcmp.

Comment: Thanks. The one thing I was not certain about: For large buffers, will memcmp "stop" at first difference, or will it always check the full size? Is there a benefit of "junking it down" in a for-loop in this case?

Comment: The standard doesn't guarantee that it will stop on the first difference (because the standard doesn't tend to offer performance guarantees like that).  *In practise*, all implementations will stop at the first difference (or possibly soon after the first difference, if the implementor thinks that reducing the number of branches will improve overall performance).